# JavaFX - Adding a ScrollPane popup which closes when user clicks out of it

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

My title is badly worded because my problem is very hard to describe, so I drew an image for it:

[image]

I have an ImageView object which represents a pile of cards (not poker cards but just used them as an example). When this image view is clicked, I need a window to popup that features a ScrollPane and shows them all the card objects that are in the linked list. When the user clicks anywhere outside of the window (and later on, any right mouse button click) the scrollpane window needs to close.

Ways that I have already tried:

- Scene with APPLICATION_MODAL. Then did Scene.showAndWait(). I didn't like this method because it made another application on the user's taskbar. It also felt clunky and just bad.
- Changed my root pane to a StackPane, then added this Scrollpane to the stackpane when the user clicked on the deck. This for some reason was really slow and seemed really obtrusive. It was also annoying because my alternate class needed to have access to the root pane (since when it closes, it needs to go to the root StackPane and call .remove() on itself).

Are there any other better ways to accomplish this? My application is going to have many of these piles and so this framework needs to work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would still propose to open a new `Stage` with some restrictions to solve your issues with this approach.

You can use the [initOwner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) property of the `Stage` to have another `Stage` as owner, therefore no other icon will appear on the taskbar.

You can use the [initStyle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initStyle-javafx.stage.StageStyle-) property with [TRANSPARENT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#TRANSPARENT) or [UNDECORATED](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UNDECORATED) `StageStlye`, this will ensure that only the content is visible.

And in the end you can use the [focusedProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#focusedProperty--) to check whether the `Stage` lost focus to close it.

**Example**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            Button b = new Button("Open deck");
            b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    Stage popupStage = new Stage();

                    popupStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
                    popupStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    Scene sc = new Scene(new ScrollPane(), 300, 300);
                    popupStage.setScene(sc);

                    popupStage.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                        @Override
                        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
                                Boolean newValue) {
                            if(!newValue)
                                popupStage.close();

                        }
                    });

                    popupStage.show();

                }
            });

            root.setCenter(b);


            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It is also possible of course to not open it in a new `Stage`, but draw a `ScrollPane` inside the current `Stage` which **overlaps** the content of the `Stage` using for example an [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html) or [Group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) as root, but the first solution has the advantage that you are not bound to the dimensions of main `Stage` (the popup can have any size that you want).

Comment: Thanks so much. I had no idea that was possible.

Comment: I hope this helps:) If any tailoring needed (as it is closing as soon as it losts the focus) and you need help, just comment here and I will update the asnwer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a low level system hook that catches the mouse events.

http://kra.lc/blog/2016/02/java-global-system-hook/ or https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases

I hope that is what you needed, otherwise i got your question wrong.

Comment: What is a system hook? I can detect the mouse event fine, it's the pane that is the hard part.

Comment: @Hatefiend Oh i am sorry, i got it wrong. i thought you also mean mouseclicks outside of the window.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I meant mouse clicks outside of the popup window (the one showing what is inside the pile of cards)